how to structure my code to have retries in a function that return a Promises
so i have not really worked too much with C++ promise and future and i am unable to understand how i can add retries to a method that returns a promise but i have a method like below
promise<void> foo(Request){
/// There are N steps and i want to retry one of them <
/// if any one of the step fails the function can return 
promise<void>::reject(std::errc::bar);
....
/// we are at the end, everything succeed
return promise::fulfilled();
}

But the issue is that one of the steps is flaky and i want to add retries for it, please note that i am not thinking of adding sleep and retry again because i do not want to block the thread.
so what i want is to move all the execution code in some new internal method like this
promise<void> executeFoo(Request request){
...
/// have all code here
...
}

and than
promise<void> foo(Request request){
/// have a utility class that can invoke methods on some delay 
/// and a fixed number of time, so something like 
return promise<void> {Util::Retry(/*delay_between_retries*/, /*number_Of_retries*/, /*some_other_thread*/, [&request](){
executeFoo(request);
})};

what is confusing me is that once promise foo(Request request) executes and promise is returned for the first time how can i fulfill/reject the promise later for consequent retries or should i cache the promise but thsi call can occur for other requests as well. I was not able to find any code online that showed how promise can work with retries, but if someone has some resources please do share. I understand that my code snippet are not actual code  so any insights or pointers in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

can you show the definition of promise? It doesn't look like std::promise

yes it is not std::promise, not sure i can share the definition of that class here, if you can specify what you want to look, i can look and get back to you. But assume if this was a std::promise , do you have any references on how retry logic might look so that i can go from there.

The retry function has to create it's own std::future, from a function that loops trying the provided action.
class max_tries_exceeded : std::exception
{
    max_tries_exceeded() : std::exception("maximum tries exceeded") {}
};

template <typename Rep, typename Period, typename F, typename... Args>
std::future<void> retry(std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> timeout, size_t tries, F fn, Args... args) {
    return std::async([=]() mutable {
        for (; tries; --tries) {
            auto result = fn(args...);
            if (result.wait_for(timeout) == std::future_status::ready) {
                try {
                    return result.get();
                } catch() {}
            }
        }
        throw max_tries_exceeded{};
    }
}

